# Google Analytics Ecommerce / Difference between 'ec:addItem', 'ec:addTransaction' and 'ec:send'

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, tracking

I would look for some feedback on [tracking user activity on an commerce website using th google analytics commerce capabilities](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce).

I can't fully understand those 3 parts :

- Adding an item (`ecommerce:addItem`) : obviously when some user add a thing to the cart
- Adding a Transaction (`ecommerce:addTransaction`) : that's where I'm very confused
- Sending the data (`ecommerce:send`) : that's obvious

Can those 3 event append at a different moment ? in what manner ?
What would be a real-world use case that would make you use execute `ecommerce:addTransaction` and  `ecommerce:send` at a different moment ?

This thing makes me wonder a lot, and I'd like to have some experienced feedback on this as you tend to easily break your stats if something is not done week enough

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

So the main purpose right here is to get stats for the pending orders (you add stuff to your cart), and the complete orders (you paid for the things you added).

Right now I only send it all when the order is complete, and things are working pretty good in analytics, but I just don't know anything about the ones that did not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was a lack of knowledge.

[Simple ecommerce plugin](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce?hl=fr#transaction)  has nothing to do with the [enhanced ecommerce plugin](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce?hl=fr#transaction)

You won't track that much with the first one, except the checkouts. A plain, one order at a time, revenue value.

If you want a deep insight on your users behaviors (when i say deep, I mean it), You have to go for the second one.

We might be able to debate over the unusefullness of the first one; and the fact that its existence in itself compared to the second is completely misleading, as when you first get in, as usual with google, you get flooded by an endless documentation

Answer (score 0):

`ecommerce:addItem` does not add items to a cart; it adds items to a *transaction* (with "conventional" ecommcerce tracking there is no cart tracking, you'd have to use enhanced ecommerce tracking. Actually your title refers to enhanced ("ec:") and your question to conventional ecommerce ("ecommerce:") tracking).

So `ecommerce:addTransaction` starts a transaction; here goes the stuff that affects the transaction as a whole, like transaction id, tax on the total purchase or shipping costs.

Now that you have started the transaction you can add items to it that are associated via the transaction id.

Finally the `ecommerce:send` command tells Universal Analytics that the transaction should be processed on the server. "send" is actuall a misnomer; addItem and addTransaction do already send data to the server (they each create an request to the tracking server and thus count towards your hit quota).

The reason for this is, as far as I can tell, that the information is transmitted via url parameters (you call the Google Analytics endpoint which returns an transparent pixel). The maximum length for an url request is limited (actual limits depend on browser and browser version).

So the transaction is broken up into multiple parts not because you want to execute the commands at different moments but so it can be transmitted via Url parameters without being truncated. The `send` command merely tells that you are now finished adding new parts to the transaction and the data can now be processed.

Comment: So that's not the way to track cart abandonment ? Those three methods have to be sent at the same time ?